# Создание тени окна в не клиентской области WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

В общем и целом, есть стандартный стиль окна, который меня не устраивает. Я отказываюсь от его использования путем установления свойств WindowStyle="None" и последующим AllowsTransparency="True". Переопределяю стиль окна и указываю DropShadowEffect. Все отображается корректно до поры до времени.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

DropShadowEffect реализуется путем отступа от главного контейнера, который входит в компоновку. В мое случае отступ с каждой стороны 5.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И когда оно прилипает к какому то из краев экрана, область тени является частью приложения и не уходит за пределы. Видны отступы, которых не должно быть вовсе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если использовать WindowChrome в своем стиле и стандартную тень, то она будет не такой, какой я ее хочу видеть. Слишком резкая и большой разброс.Но работает она как надо.

Главный вопрос. Как создать тень не включенную в область приложения и без всяких отступов, которые в дальнейшем при прилипании к одной из части окна, будут видны как здесь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Размер окна делается больше на размер тени, а грид, который имеет фон - меньше. Считай окно - это и само окно - и тень от него. А вообще если не используете узорчатые края и прозрачность, проще использовать стандартное окно, только заголовок ему отключить и нарисовать свой. И вставьте XAML текстом, а не картинкой.

Comment: Именно так и сделано у меня в данном примере. Все что мне необходимо - чтобы тень не была частью приложения, ибо при развертывания начало приложения считается с начала тени, а не с окна. Отсюда и отступы появляются

Comment: Используйте отрицательные марджины при развертывании.

Comment: Даже если использовать отрицательные, при делении экрана на две равные части, тень с моего приложения при активном фокусе не накладывается на другое приложение, а попросту отталкивает до начало тени. В следствии чего так же проблел

Comment: На последнем скрине это видно наглядно

Comment: Здесь уже хитрости, можете проверять, если приложение занимает ровно полэкрана, то есть высота 1, ширина 0,5, а левый верхний угол либо в углу экрана, либо на верхней границе, то тень не показывать. Ну или других костылей напридумывать. Типа если хотя-бы одна из сторон окна совпадает с границей экрана, выключать тень. Здесь уж на что фантазии хватит.

Comment: Только особенность в том, что мне нужно ее отобразить и она должна падать на другое приложение. Работать точно так же как обычная тень, но не такая резкая и радиус меньше. Скорее всего нужно лезть в WinApi

Comment: У вас тень по факту внутри окна. Это само по себе костыль, не надо заклеивать костыль другими костылями. Меняйте подход, если такие запросы к позиционированию окна.

Comment: Разобраться бы с WinApi и изменить тень WindowChrome, которая является стандартной. Мысли только в эту сторону